# How can I show webkit inspector in tidesdk

Tags: tidesdk

When I try to right click and show webkit developer tools in tideSDK nothing happens, No context menu appears.
This doesn't work either ??

```
$(".inspect").bind("click", function() {
    try {
        Ti.UI.currentWindow.showInspector();
    } catch(e) {
        alert(e.toString());
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you provide information about the operating system / architecture..

Comment: I am using windows 8 x64.

Comment: I have personally not verified in win8 x64 but in all other platform it does work fine .. so not sure what would be issue .. I will check the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The web inspector/developer tools console only works when you are using **Launch App** from *TideSDK Developer* (during development of your app). Once you execute the packaged app after using **Package with Runtime**, the inspector is not enabled. Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Note that you should also be able to just run your Tide application in debug mode.
e.g.

```
myAppBuiltByTide.exe --debug
```

Running in debug mode:

1. Opens the debug console, in addition to your application window, and
2. Enables the 'Show Inspector' right click option